# Como hago para insertar la fecha y hora en la base de datos con php?

Tags: php

No me deja insertar la hora con el siguiente codigo la base de datos es con mysql y estoy usando heidiSQL

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM buseta1 WHERE  id = :codigo');
$statement->execute(array(':codigo' => $codigoEst));


    // Comparamos si los datos ingresados son iguales a los que estan en la base de datos
$resultado = $statement->fetch();
if ($resultado !== false) {
    $_SESSION['codigo'] = $codigoEst;

    echo "<script>
            alert('Codigo Ingresado Correctamente');

</script>";

    $FecHr = date('d/m/y H:i');
    $Consulta = "INSERT INTO buseta1(fecha)

    VALUES ('$FecHr');";

    mysqli_query($Consulta, $conexion);
```

Tambien ya probe con NOW() y sigue igual, probe en la base de datos cambiando a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP y sigue igual en 0000-00-00

```
$FecHr = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $Consulta = "INSERT INTO buseta1(fecha) VALUES (NOW());";

    mysqli_query($conexion, $Consulta);
```

---

Sigue sin registrarme la fecha a la base de datos, Me aparece asi la fecha en la bd  0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
$FecHr = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $Consulta = "INSERT INTO buseta1 (fecha) VALUES ('$FecHr');";
    mysqli_query($Consulta, $conexion);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Si esa columna debe tomar la fecha actual, lo puedes poner en la configuración de la tabla: `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, así, cada vez que se inserte una fila esa columna tomará el valor de la fecha/hora actual, o bien usar `NOW()` directamente en la inserción: `INSERT INTO buseta1 (fecha) VALUES (NOW());` Para esto no necesitas tomar la fecha desde PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Los formatos para guardar en la bd es `Y-m-d H:i:s` (2019-03-30 19:19:38) o puedes usar [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

```
$FecHr = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$Consulta = "INSERT INTO buseta1 (fecha) VALUES ('$FecHr');";
```